# How to force a net.tcp mex endpoint (mexTcpBinding) to participate in port sharing?

Tags: wcf, net.tcp, mex-bindings

I have a WCF service which is hosted as a Windows Service. We would like to enable a mex endpoint at the same address (but with a '/mex' suffix). I have been trying to do this (unsuccessfully) using the following configuration:

```
<system.serviceModel>

  <services>
    <service
      name="MyCompany.MyService"
      behaviorConfiguration="defaultServiceBehavior">

      <host>
        <baseAddresses>
          <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost"/>
        </baseAddresses>
      </host>

      <endpoint
        address="MyService"
        binding="netTcpBinding"
        contract="MyCompany.IMyService"
        bindingConfiguration="netTcpBindingConfig"
        />

      <endpoint
        address="MyService/mex"
        binding="mexTcpBinding"
        contract="IMetadataExchange"
        />

    </service>
  </services>

  <behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
      <behavior name="defaultServiceBehavior">
        <serviceMetadata />
      </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
  </behaviors>

  <bindings>
    <netTcpBinding>
      <binding name="netTcpBindingConfig" portSharingEnabled="true" />
    </netTcpBinding>
  </bindings>

</system.serviceModel>
```

When it runs, the service host throws an `AddressAlreadyInUseException` complaining that "There is already a listener on IP endpoint 0.0.0.0:808". This actually makes sense to me because the port sharing service has opened that port in order to serve the `MyService` endpoint along with any other services requesting to share that port on this machine.

So it seems that the mex endpoint wants exlusive access to port 808. I can work around this by tweaking the mex endpoint like so:

```
<endpoint
  address="net.tcp://localhost:818/MyService/mex"
  binding="mexTcpBinding"
  contract="IMetadataExchange"
  />
```

This means that the mex endpoint now has its own exclusive port. The downside with this is that any other service which wants to expose a mex endpoint will also need a unique port for its mex endpoint. This makes it very unpredictable when looking for mex endpoints.

Is there a way to force the mex endpoint to participate in port sharing?

Comment: Just a thought: Add bindingConfiguration="netTcpBindingConfig"
 to the mex endpoint?

Comment: @Torben Yeah, I tried that. When I do that, the mex endpoint doesn't have a problem sharing, but it does completely fail to produce any metadata.

Answer (score 9):

Two options:

1. The easy way: Change the entire binding for the mex point to netTcpBinding and have it reuse your bindingConfiguration. mexTCPBinding is only meant to be a convenience and is optional. If its not working for you, don’t use it.
2. The hard way: You can modify the mexTCPBinding to enable sharing. The only example I’ve seen is in code here: [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20150701084740/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/drnick/archive/2006/08/23/713297.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried changing mexTcpBinding to netTcpBinding but no dice. When I do that, the service starts up and doesn't complain about sharing problems (which is cool) but completely fails to respond to mex requests (which is uncool). Presumably there's something else I need to configure if I use netTcpBinding that I'm not aware of?

Comment: @Damian did you ever solve this? Weirdly we're seeing this issue on my local machine, but not in production